# Custom circular progress indicator having multiple value

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a circle progress indicator like that:

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: You have to build your own custom progress indicator. This is a long task and you should show how much you have worked on so others can help you achieve what you are missing. So share your current code for this widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi color like this in CircularProgressIndicator().

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
 import 'package:mis/app_extensions.dart';

class LoadingIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
const LoadingIndicator({ Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<LoadingIndicator> createState() =>_LoadingIndicatorState();
}

class _LoadingIndicatorState extends State<LoadingIndicator>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late AnimationController animationController;

@override
void initState() {
animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
animationController.repeat();
super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
animationController.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
    valueColor: animationController
        .drive(ColorTween(begin: AppColors.blueTop, end: AppColors.red)),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: If you don't explain what is `animationController ` @Dhiraj  will not understand what it is!

Comment: Better like that!